# How do I run Angular unit tests against specific Chrome version?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I recently noticed on my Windows 10 PC that Chrome updated to a higher build number. Now when running unit tests on headless Chrome, I am seeing Jasmine timeout issues with `async` functions.

Is there a way to run the unit tests against an older version of Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reading, I realized Chrome MSI installers won't allow you to have multiple versions on PC. Also, Google does not archive older versions of Chrome.

The problem arose when my PC auto-updated from Chrome `76.0.3809.80` to `76.0.3809.100`.

I ended up downgrading to Chrome `75.0.3770.80` 64-bit version. This stopped the async methods from timing out. [You can find the downloads here](https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php).

The other item I found is that it is possible to tell Karma the path to the browser executable. [The Karma documentation explains this](http://karma-runner.github.io/4.0/config/browsers.html). This is a small side note but useful.

I am using Angular 7: `"@angular/core": "^7.2.15"`.

Unfortunately, I am still not sure what the root cause is :-(

Comment: @KarenManukyan No updates unfortunately. I don't know if there are other developers who are experiencing this issue.